# Qwebkit and flash player,why its not working in windows

Tags: qt, flash, qwebkit

im using Qwebkit and every time im loading youtube , its asking me to download the latest
flash player plugin , even so i already installed the plugin and i can see youtube videos
in firefox and explorer very well
what is the deal with Qwebkit and Flash plagin ?

Comment: The answer is to add  :
 defaultSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, settings.value(QLatin1String("enableJavascript"), true).toBool());
    defaultSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, settings.value(QLatin1String("enablePlugins"), true).toBool());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way of doing it. Qt in windows doesn't use by default the flash plugin even if you have installed it for firefox. The solution is to manually copy the plugin dll into your compiled application directory (I mean in the same directory than the executable is installed).

I did it more than a year ago so I'm not totally sure if it has to be directly in the directory or under a folder called plugins. Try both and one of them should work.

The flash plugin dll should be in your firefox directory, if not do a search in google and there are several pages in which you can download it.

You also need to activate plug-ins support for QWebView. I think that was done in the pro file, but I have been doing some research and it maybe done changing the web settings:

```
    websettings.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled,True)
```

Comment: not working , i just compiled with flex compiler and i have in my windows installed flash player version 10 , some portion of the player does load ,but without seing ant thing . the same html code workes fine in firefox 3.6

Comment: That is very weird, I have used it before. But I don't have the code so I'm not 100% sure of where do you have to store the dll. If you check in the QWebkit documentation it says where the it looks for plugins in the differents OS. Try to use one of the listed directories. And you also have to enable plugins in webkit. That is done in the pro file of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to adobe.com and download the plugin for Other Browsers (Firefox, Safari, Opera), and re-install...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very simple to solve. Just add the following lines to your code:

```
QWebSettings *defaultSettings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
defaultSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
defaultSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to report on my experience of enabling flash in QWebKit, do the following:

> download firefox and install flash player for firefox, 
>   enable plug-ins in QWebKit (QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);) 
>   then recompile your Qt Application. 
>   Now flash should work fine.